# Question about graded Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, lie-algebras

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_Lie_algebra), a graded Lie algebra is defined as a direct sum of vector spaces
$$
\mathfrak{g} = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathfrak{g}_i \tag{1}
$$
such that the Lie bracket satisfies
$$
[\mathfrak{g}_i, \mathfrak{g}_j] \subseteq \mathfrak{g}_{i+j} \tag{2}
$$

So from a physicists point of view, I interpret equation (2) as follows:

The Lie bracket of an element $x \in \mathfrak{g}_i$ and an element $y \in \mathfrak{g}_j$ will be an element in the vector space $\mathfrak{g}_{i+j}$. But let us now, for definiteness, assume the graded Lie algebra is given by
$$
\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{g}_1 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_2 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_3
$$
Then for $x \in \mathfrak{g}_2$ and $y \in \mathfrak{g}_3$
$$
[x, y] \subseteq \mathfrak{g}_{2+3} = \mathfrak{g}_5
$$
But what is $\mathfrak{g}_5$ in this example (considering that we have only assumed the existence of $\mathfrak{g}_1$, $\mathfrak{g}_2$ and $\mathfrak{g}_3$)?

Comment: In the above definition, $\mathfrak{g}_i$ is just a vector space *not* a Lie algebra. The only Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ out of $\mathfrak{g}_i$ is $\mathfrak{g}_0$. It would not make sense if $\mathfrak{g}_{i\neq 0}$ are subalegbras.

Comment: @Hamed thank you for pointing that out to me!

Comment: more precisely, for $i\neq 0$ $\mathfrak{g}_i$ is a subalgebra iff it's an abelian subalgebra (which often occurs! e.g. if all $\mathfrak{g}_i$ are 1-dimensional, as in the usual grading of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ in $\{-1,0,1\}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ${\cal g}_i$ will be zero for $i>3$ so if $x\in {\cal g}_2, y\in {\cal g}_3, [x,y]=0$.